# Wi-Fi network not working on Fedora 32 - connection times out

Tags: fedora, wifi, usb, internet, iwlwifi

I am running Fedora 32 on a used HP Z420 workstation. My Internet connection worked all OK when I was using an Ethernet connection, but after I moved to an apartment that did not have an Ethernet output and had to use Wi-Fi instead, I can't get the Wi-Fi connection on the computer to work.

The problem is not in the Wi-Fi connection itself, as the Windows 10 laptop I have been using for remote work is able to connect to the Wi-Fi all OK.

I am using a TP-Link TL-WN823N USB Wi-Fi adapter plugged in to the computer's USB port. When I run lsusb it shows the adapter as:
`Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2357:0109 TP-Link TL-WN823N v2/v3 [Realtek RTL8192EU]`

When I boot up the computer and log in to Fedora, the system is able to find the Wi-Fi network as its name shows up when I click on the network icon on the taskbar, along with several other Wi-Fi networks (that belong to other people and whose passwords I don't know). When I click on the network name, Fedora asks me for a network password. When I type it and click "Connect", nothing happens. I don't get connected and I don't even get a message about a wrong password or anything.

Here is what appears when I run dmesg:

```
[  622.856644] iwlwifi: unknown parameter 'wd_disable' ignored
[  622.856648] iwlwifi: unknown parameter 'bt_coex_acrive' ignored
[  622.856707] Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
[  640.346741] wlp0s26u1u3: authenticate with 9e:0e:8b:55:27:c7
[  640.365595] wlp0s26u1u3: send auth to 9e:0e:8b:55:27:c7 (try 1/3)
[  640.569164] wlp0s26u1u3: send auth to 9e:0e:8b:55:27:c7 (try 2/3)
[  640.777145] wlp0s26u1u3: send auth to 9e:0e:8b:55:27:c7 (try 3/3)
[  640.985121] wlp0s26u1u3: authentication with 9e:0e:8b:55:27:c7 timed out
```

I have read this SuperUser StackExchange post: https://superuser.com/questions/911635/wifi-authentication-times-out and tried the solution. It didn't work. It seems Fedora is ignoring the "wd_disable" parameter. It is also ignoring another parameter "bt_coex_acrive" (yes, it is really spelled "acrive" in the dmesg output, not "active") that I don't know where it comes from. It does not appear in any file in the directory /etc/modprobe.d.

I am able to type this StackExchange post because I'm currently at work in my company's office, where there is a working Internet connection.

Does anyone have an idea what is causing this and how I can fix it? I can provide more details if needed but there is a lag because I have to switch between my home computer (to diagnose the problem) and my work computer (to report it to StackExchange).

If the solution involves installing more software with dnf then I don't know how that would work as to be able to use dnf I would need an Internet connection in the first place.

Update 6 November 2021: I have installed the rtl8192eu kernel module found here: https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver
That did not help. Nothing changed. The Wi-Fi adapter recognises the network but is unable to connect to it.

Here is what I found on dmesg output:

```
[   15.561144] usb 1-1.3: RTL8192EU rev B (SMIC) 2T2R, TX queues 3, WiFi=1, BT=0, GPS=0, HI PA=0
[   15.561150] usb 1-1.3: RTL8192EU MAC: d0:37:45:e0:a6:34
[   15.561154] usb 1-1.3: rtl8xxxu: Loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192eu_nic.bin
[   15.620484] usb 1-1.3: Firmware revision 19.0 (signature 0x92e1)
[   15.625336] do the RAM reset
[   15.716296] audit: type=1130 audit(1636220825.389:87): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=systemd-journal-flush comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
[   15.862600] audit: type=1130 audit(1636220825.536:88): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=lvm2-pvscan@8:35 comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
[   15.866219] audit: type=1130 audit(1636220825.539:89): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=lvm2-monitor comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
[   16.628660] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8xxxu
[   16.705001] 8192eu: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[   16.706111] 8192eu: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[   16.729951] RTW: module init start
[   16.729953] RTW: rtl8192eu v5.2.19.1_25633.20171222_COEX20171113-0047
[   16.729954] RTW: build time: Nov  6 2021 19:39:30
[   16.729956] RTW: rtl8192eu BT-Coex version = COEX20171113-0047
[   16.729968] RTW: rtw_inetaddr_notifier_register
[   16.730006] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8192eu
[   16.730008] RTW: module init ret=0
[   16.751606] rtl8xxxu 1-1.3:1.0 wlp0s26u1u3: renamed from wlan0
[ 1246.417272] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[ 1246.496419] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=2357, idProduct=0109, bcdDevice= 2.00
[ 1246.496422] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1246.496423] usb 1-1.3: Product: 802.11n NIC 
[ 1246.496424] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: Realtek 
[ 1246.496425] usb 1-1.3: SerialNumber: 00e04c000001
[ 1246.664668] usb 1-1.3: Vendor: Realtek
[ 1246.664670] usb 1-1.3: Product: \x03802.11n NI
[ 1246.664671] usb 1-1.3: Serial: 
[ 1246.664672] usb 1-1.3: rtl8192eu_parse_efuse: dumping efuse (0x200 bytes):
[ 1246.664674] usb 1-1.3: 00: 29 81 00 7c 01 40 03 00
[ 1246.664675] usb 1-1.3: 08: 40 74 04 50 14 00 00 00
[ 1246.664676] usb 1-1.3: 10: 25 25 26 28 28 28 28 28
[ 1246.664677] usb 1-1.3: 18: 29 2a 2a f2 ef ef ff ff
[ 1246.664678] usb 1-1.3: 20: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[ 1246.664678] usb 1-1.3: 28: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[ 1246.664679] usb 1-1.3: 30: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[ 1246.664680] usb 1-1.3: 38: ff ff 2b 2b 2a 2b 2b 2b
[ 1246.664681] usb 1-1.3: 40: 2d 2d 2c 2b 2b f2 ef ef
[ 1246.664682] usb 1-1.3: 48: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[ 1246.664682] usb 1-1.3: 50: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[ 1246.664683] usb 1-1.3: 58: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[ 1246.664684] usb 1-1.3: 60: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[ 1246.664685] usb 1-1.3: 68: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[ 1246.664686] usb 1-1.3: 70: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[ 1246.664686] usb 1-1.3: 78: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[ 1246.664687] usb 1-1.3: 80: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[ 1246.664688] usb 1-1.3: 88: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[ 1246.664689] usb 1-1.3: 90: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[ 1246.664689] usb 1-1.3: 98: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[ 1246.664690] usb 1-1.3: a0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[ 1246.664691] usb 1-1.3: a8: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[ 1246.664692] usb 1-1.3: b0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[ 1246.664693] usb 1-1.3: b8: a1 1f 1f 00 00 00 ff ff
[ 1246.664693] usb 1-1.3: c0: ff 01 00 10 00 00 00 ff
[ 1246.664694] usb 1-1.3: c8: 00 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff
[ 1246.664695] usb 1-1.3: d0: 57 23 09 01 e7 47 02 d0
[ 1246.664696] usb 1-1.3: d8: 37 45 e0 a6 34 0a 03 52
[ 1246.664697] usb 1-1.3: e0: 65 61 6c 74 65 6b 20 0e
[ 1246.664697] usb 1-1.3: e8: 03 38 30 32 2e 31 31 6e
[ 1246.664698] usb 1-1.3: f0: 20 4e 49 43 20 00 00 ff
[ 1246.664699] usb 1-1.3: f8: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[ 1246.664700] usb 1-1.3: 100: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[ 1246.664701] usb 1-1.3: 108: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[ 1246.664701] usb 1-1.3: 110: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 0d
[ 1246.664702] usb 1-1.3: 118: 03 00 05 00 30 00 00 00
[ 1246.664703] usb 1-1.3: 120: 00 93 ff ff ff ff ff ff
[ 1246.664704] usb 1-1.3: 128: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[ 1246.664705] usb 1-1.3: 130: f6 a8 98 2d 03 92 98 00
[ 1246.664705] usb 1-1.3: 138: fc 8c 00 11 9b 44 02 0a
[ 1246.664706] usb 1-1.3: 140: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[ 1246.664707] usb 1-1.3: 148: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[ 1246.664708] usb 1-1.3: 150: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[ 1246.664708] usb 1-1.3: 158: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[ 1246.664709] usb 1-1.3: 160: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[ 1246.664710] usb 1-1.3: 168: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[ 1246.664711] usb 1-1.3: 170: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[ 1246.664712] usb 1-1.3: 178: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[ 1246.664712] usb 1-1.3: 180: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[ 1246.664713] usb 1-1.3: 188: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[ 1246.664714] usb 1-1.3: 190: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[ 1246.664715] usb 1-1.3: 198: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[ 1246.664716] usb 1-1.3: 1a0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[ 1246.664716] usb 1-1.3: 1a8: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[ 1246.664717] usb 1-1.3: 1b0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[ 1246.664718] usb 1-1.3: 1b8: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[ 1246.664719] usb 1-1.3: 1c0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[ 1246.664720] usb 1-1.3: 1c8: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[ 1246.664720] usb 1-1.3: 1d0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[ 1246.664721] usb 1-1.3: 1d8: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[ 1246.664722] usb 1-1.3: 1e0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[ 1246.664723] usb 1-1.3: 1e8: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[ 1246.664723] usb 1-1.3: 1f0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[ 1246.664724] usb 1-1.3: 1f8: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[ 1246.664725] usb 1-1.3: RTL8192EU rev B (SMIC) 2T2R, TX queues 3, WiFi=1, BT=0, GPS=0, HI PA=0
[ 1246.664727] usb 1-1.3: RTL8192EU MAC: d0:37:45:e0:a6:34
[ 1246.664729] usb 1-1.3: rtl8xxxu: Loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192eu_nic.bin
[ 1246.664907] usb 1-1.3: Firmware revision 19.0 (signature 0x92e1)
[ 1247.564794] usb 1-1.3: rtl8192eu_rx_iqk_path_b: Path B RX IQK failed!
[ 1247.597043] usb 1-1.3: rtl8192eu_rx_iqk_path_b: Path B RX IQK failed!
[ 1247.646418] usb 1-1.3: rtl8192eu_rx_iqk_path_a: Path A RX IQK failed!
[ 1247.678543] usb 1-1.3: rtl8192eu_rx_iqk_path_a: Path A RX IQK failed!
[ 1247.840911] rtl8xxxu 1-1.3:1.0 wlp0s26u1u3: renamed from wlan0
[ 1256.125789] wlp0s26u1u3: authenticate with e2:31:6b:57:db:55
[ 1256.147605] wlp0s26u1u3: send auth to e2:31:6b:57:db:55 (try 1/3)
[ 1256.352156] wlp0s26u1u3: send auth to e2:31:6b:57:db:55 (try 2/3)
[ 1256.560135] wlp0s26u1u3: send auth to e2:31:6b:57:db:55 (try 3/3)
[ 1256.768132] wlp0s26u1u3: authentication with e2:31:6b:57:db:55 timed out
```

Comment: What's the content of `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`?  What is the output of `cat /sys/module/iwlwifi/parameters/11n_disable` and `cat /sys/module/iwlwifi/parameters/bt_coex_active`?

Comment: /etc/modprobe.d/iwlfwifi.conf: ````options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 wd_disable=1````
/sys/module/iwlwifi/parameters/11n_disable: ````1````
/sys/module/iwlwifi/parameters/bt_coex_active: ````Y````

Comment: I have added more information and more dmesg output after trying to install a kernel module for the device drivers.